# Detect a workspace switch from p4v

Tags: perforce

If I have a workspace open in P4V and I switch workspaces is there a way to notify or detect that the switch has happened externally?

The workspace contains an editor and needs to checkout files to modify them. I'm worried that a switch via P4V would leave the editor unaware that the files are now from a different stream.

I would rather have a way to detect this in the editor rather than having to notify from P4V if possible.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying your editor checks out the files automatically? That's common, so you're not on your own. What editor is it, if I may ask?

Do you know how your editor talks to Perforce? Am I right thinking that it issues `p4.exe` (the cmdline tool) commands, e.g. `p4 edit`? (The other way would be using one of the P4 APIs, e.g. p4java or p4python.) If so, the `p4 edit` commands already do not respect the P4V workspace setting. The `p4.exe` cmdline tool will work with the p4 workspace specified in [one of six ways](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4guide/chapter.configuration.html#DB5-24024). To always use the right client,

- have a `P4CONFIG` file specifying `P4CLIENT=[client name]` in the root of each of your workspaces
- change the p4 integration of your editor in such a way that the `p4 edit` command will always be run effectively from within the given workspace (in the sense of CWD); you can use the `-d` switch for this, e.g. when checking out `C:\workspaces\wksp1\foo\bar\baz.c` you would call `p4 -d C:\workspaces\wksp1\foo\bar edit C:\workspaces\wksp1\foo\bar\baz.c`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is actually for Unity but was wondering from a more generic point of view and P4 support in Unity (from built in functionality and from P4 Connect) are terrible so would rather go around them. 

With regards to P4CONFIG, are you saying to keep that in source control? Wouldn't that mean it would only work for one person?

If not and its kept out of source control, I'm assuming each user will then need to manually create the file. Does the file get updated when a switch is executed in P4V?   

Thank you.
Alex

Comment: You don't typically keep the P4CONFIG in the source control. It conceptually replaces things like environment variables or registry settings, which also aren't versioned. Yes, each user should set up their own P4CONFIG (but they don't have to... depends on how they work - for some env variables may be the right thing to do). The trick is having one P4CONFIG in the root of each workspace/client, each setting P4CLIENT accordingly.

Comment: Hold on - you're asking "when a switch is executed in P4V" - No, none of the "six ways" above affect P4V, the visual client. In P4V, you set these things up (1) when you start P4V, there's a dialog that asks you which client you want to use, and (2) when you switch clients. The "six ways" apply to `p4.exe` (the cmdline client). Are you using P4V? Or are you struggling with a "terrible" Unity-P4 plugin? Or are you writing your own automation?

Answer (score 0):

If the user is using a new workspace, they will also be working with a different set of files, so there's hopefully not much chance for confusion there.  (Unless they've made multiple workspaces with the same Root, in which case they're doing their very best to shoot off their own kneecaps.)

If they've switched streams within the current workspace, you can detect this with a command like "p4 info", "p4 client -o", or "p4 stream -o".

Comment: This is mainly for the case when someone wants to switch from main to their dev stream or put a fix in a release stream.

I've found that commands like p4 info don't pick up the current workspace unless you manually setup up your client spec on the command line, which would nullify the point of detecting the switch.

Comment: You'll be able to get the current **stream** from `p4 info` as long as you already know the **workspace**, but if you don't know the workspace you're out of luck.  Ideally you have `P4CONFIG` files set up in each of your workspace roots (this is pretty standard practice for CLI users since it makes everything easy).  If you're writing a tool that's being executed outside of P4V but it wants to try to figure out how the workspaces are set up, you could query the server for workspaces bound to the current host and then check their Roots to see which one you're in.